# Malloc with strings in C

Tags: c, string, malloc

This codes stop working when I type the character position I want to find, plus, i need to remake it using the str as a pointer and a malloc for it

```
int main(void)
{

    char str[10];
    int pos;

    puts("Type a text");
    gets(str);
    puts("Type a position");
    scanf("%d", pos);

    pos = pos - 1;

    printf("%s",  str[pos]);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the error? make sure str is alwas '\0'-terminated

Comment: @jev my code stop working and return some memory trash.

Comment: re. malloc, show us what you tried. There are plenty of posts on here about how to malloc that you can read if you're not sure.

Comment: i tried this, seems to work whit any size. http://pastebin.com/xQkcdD62

Comment: **Never** use the `gets()` function. It is inherently unsafe, and has been removed from the language. If you type more than 9 characters in response to the `Type a text` prompt, it will clobber memory adjacent to `str`. Use `fgets` instead (and note that it will leave the `'\n'` character in the array).

Comment: Do you have `#include <stdio.h>` at the top of your source file? If so, you neglected to show it. If not, add it.

Comment: @KeithThompson i do have <stdio.h> included. how do i use fgets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want to do:

```
scanf("%d", &pos);
```

Comment: worked, but i still need to use malloc for the string size, any ideia?

Comment: You *definitely* need to use `&pos`, not `pos`, when calling `scanf`. You also need to fix the format string as suggested by the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

`str[pos]` is a single character, not a string, so you can print it with `%c`, but not with `%s`

You want:

```
printf("%c",  str[pos]);
system("pause");
```

Answer (score 0):

The following line is wrong:

```
  printf("%s",  str[pos]);
```

You are using the format specifier `"%s"`, which is intended to print strings, to process `str[pos]`, which is a `char`.

Since `"%s"` expect a pointer address, if you don't use with care, it's very probably that your program will be broken.